# Android Listviewitem is not clickable when its scrollable

Tags: android, listview, clickable, scrollable

The items of my ExpandableListview are not clickable when I add the following line to my Textview to show its full content:

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

My Layout for a Listviewitem is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip" android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_expandablelistitem"
        android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblExpListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/lblExpListArrow"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

Code to enable scrolling in Textview

```
lblExpListItem.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try android:clickable="true" is TextView?

Comment: I have tried it. But onChildClick is not called. It seems to be the lines `lblExpListItem.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` or `android:scrollbars="horizontal"` which prevents the onChildClick event.

Comment: Scrollable text in list item doesn't look like a good desgin. Listview only show highlights. If you want to show details, use detail view (list view->detail view). This is the correct design pattern. Also try with android:clickable="false". Now the parent's onclick should be called

Comment: Yes you are right. But it my case it must be possible to choose a list item when they differ e.g. only in one char... listitemabc (index xy), listitemabc (index xk), listitemdfc (index sdk) and so on. In my case the text of the listitem is sometimes too long to choose a specific item.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you are implementing the scrollbar in the first place on a expandable list view? If the text does not fit you might want to change the android:layout_height="55dip" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" so that the text does not get cut off when it wraps around.  I will try to find why the scrollbar itself breaks it but for now you might just want to see if the wrap content works.

Comment: The scrollbar is implemented in the textview. The line `android:scrollbars="horizontal"` is just an excerpt.

Comment: I want to set a fixed height so that every row has the same height. if the textview is too long you can scroll horizontally.

Comment: I am just wondering if that is what is making it not work.  I get that you want the fixed height but like Ata's comment on initial post it might look a little weird.